# My free app showing 'buy'?

Tags: software-center

my app in the software centre showing 'buy'  with 0.0 usd but i published it as free. I am a new ubuntu developer.What are the files that i have to upload to software centre for publishing?

Answer (score 3):

In the software centre, you "buy" free applications with a purchase price of 0.00. This is normal and expected if using the software centre when it is independently produced.

Comment: how to change that into free

Comment: You can always license the software appropriately with the GPL. If you want it to be a core application, you will need to release it as an open source project, gain enough users to enable inclusion into distributions, and work on maintaining it as such. Have you published the work in Launchpad under an open source license of any kind? If not, the freedom part of 'free' does not exist and it will always cost 0.00.

Comment: so i have to make source code available, only then it is a free software?

Comment: i used proprietary license, is not free?

Comment: Free as in freedom - no, free as in beer, maybe, free as in price, yes. However, not opening the software to modification, contribution and/or review means the price is always 0.00 and it has to be bought at that cost.You can always charge for free software, nothing in the GPL stops you from doing that. What you should allow though, is access to the source. This insure that the software remains viable beyond the lifespan of the developer and remains free.